# MySQL only show records where COUNT of GROUP_CONCAT > 1

Tags: mysql

I need a query where the result only shows records in which there are multiple values in a group concat. I'm only interested in records that have more than one value displayed in the group_contact column.

I have a change log table that stores price changes of a PO. Each change in PO price is another entry in the table. Here's my query so far:

```
SELECT PONum,  POLine, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT DocUnitCost) AS priceChanges
FROM `podetailcl` 
WHERE 1   -- ?something here saying where COUNT of price changes > 1? 
GROUP BY PONum, POLine
```

Additional Information:
[image]

I might need to use HAVING but I'm not too clear on how to structure that. I did try the suggestions on other pages but I'm still lost on this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use having for filter aggregated  result  and not where  ..

```
SELECT PONum,  POLine, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT DocUnitCost) AS priceChanges
FROM `podetailcl` 
GROUP BY PONum, POLine
having count(DISTINCT DocUnitCost)>1
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I had a feeling it would be something simple!

Comment: @S.Mason   ...sql  is a very powerful (and easy) language  ,, is  built for this  ... many thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT PONum,  POLine, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT DocUnitCost) AS priceChanges
FROM `podetailcl` 
GROUP BY PONum, POLine
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT DocUnitCost) > 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your help with this too.

Comment: @S.Mason can u upit ?

Comment: Yes, no problem! Cheers.